# pagerank computation of a directed graph with google solution

Tags: python, machine-learning, graph, networkx, data-mining

i am trying to find the page rank of the directed graph with google's approach

This is my graph:

[image]

i created my graph as;

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import sys

G = nx.DiGraph()
[G.add_node(k) for k in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
G.add_edges_from([(4, 1), (4, 2), (2, 3), (3,2), (7, 2), (8, 2), (9, 2), (6, 2), (5, 2), (5,4), (5,6), (7, 5), (8, 5), (9, 5), (10, 5), (11, 5), (6, 5)])
```

and this is the information given:

The PageRank equation is as follows.

[image]

where  r  represents the  n×1  PageRank vector with each element  ri  representing the PageRank value of node  i ,  P  represents the  n×n  transition probability matrix with each element  Pi,j  representing the transition probability from node  i  to node  j ,  PT  represents the transpose of  P ,  β  represents decay factor,  1n  represents a n×1 vector of all 1’s, and  n  represents the number of nodes in the graph.

In order to compute the PageRank values, you need to pre-process the dangling node 1 (dead end). You need to add one edge from node 1 to any other node in the graph.

```
#Transition probability matrix considering the dangling node 1
P = np.array([
              [1/11, 1/11, 1/11, 1/11, 1/11, 1/11, 1/11, 1/11, 1/11, 1/11, 1/11],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1/2, 1/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1/3, 0, 1/3, 0, 1/3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1/2, 0, 0, 1/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1/2, 0, 0, 1/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1/2, 0, 0, 1/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1/2, 0, 0, 1/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
], dtype = float)
n = P.shape[0] #number of nodes
print(n)
beta = 0.85
epsilon = 10**-6
```

and this is how i tried to solve this:

```
difference = sys.maxsize
r = np.ones(n)*(1/n)
max_iteration = 100
count = 0
localErr = sys.maxsize
while (count < max_iteration and localErr>epsilon):
  r_old = r.copy()
  r = beta * np.dot(P.transpose(), r) + ((1 - beta) * (1 / n))
  localErr = np.absolute(r - r_old).sum()
  count += 1
print(r)
rank = np.argsort(-r)
print(rank)
```

and my output is:

```
[0.03278149 0.38440115 0.34291008 0.03908709 0.08088569 0.03908709
 0.01616948 0.01616948 0.01616948 0.01616948 0.01616948]
[ 1  2  4  3  5  0  6  7  8  9 10]
```

which is not correct anyway looking at the graph !!

can anyone please help me on figuring it out !!

Comment: Why not use https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.link_analysis.pagerank_alg.pagerank.html ?

Comment: i have to do by this way !! it is meant to be done this way

Comment: Why do you think it is not correct? If you  `print(rank+1)` does it make more sense? The only difference I would make is to multiply the `localErr` by `n`...